# How to use first column in Panda to save results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm learning Python and I have some trouble with submitting my results to the kaggle titanic competition. In below surv_pred contains my result array survived, while T contains my data:

```
show_table(T,5)
# this results in :
```

> Sample data entry : 5
> PassengerId 5
> Age 0.35000000000000003
> SibSp 0.0
> Parch 0.0
> Fare 0.0008050000000000002
> RelationsOnBoard 0.0
> DatingRank 0.3
> Deck 0.0
> female 0
> harborA 0
> harborB 1
> harborC 0
> ClassUp 0
> ClassMid 0
> ClassLow 1
> HasCabin 0
> AgeUnknown 0
> Family_Size 0.0
> Fare_Per_Person 0.008050000000000002
> Cabin3thclass 1
> Cabin2ndClass 0
> Cabin1stClass 0
> CabinLuxeryClass 0
> IdealFamSize 0

```
surv_pred = clf.predict(T)
print(surv_pred)

#this results in a binary array [1 0 1 1 0 1 .... etc

# from here I have Python trouble:

ids =  T.loc['PassengerId']
submissions = pd.DataFrame('PassengerId' = ids ,'survived' = surv_pred)
submissions.to_csv("submit_v3.csv",index=False)
```

I tried various variations in the code but somehow I won't get the first column of T ea T['passengerId']. To get above code to work that is save result to a csv file. Problems in Panda and saving and selecting. `ids=T['passenderId']` won't work either.

What is wrong in above code ?

I got errors like:

> KeyError: 'the label [PassengerId] is not in the [index]'
> caused in line : ids =  T.loc['PassengerId']

I don't understand this because PassengerId is clearly there. I even tried to make that sure by placing below all above in my code.

```
    T.rename(columns={ T.columns[0]: 'PassengerId' },inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
submissions = pd.DataFrame('PassengerId' = ids ,'survived' = surv_pred)
```

generate this problem

You should do like this:

```
submissions = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId' : ids ,'survived' : surv_pred})
```

Comment: this still results in KeyError: 'the label [PassengerId] is not in the [index]'     
ids =  T.loc['PassengerId']
which i dont understand because PassengerId is there

Comment: Can you try `ids = T. PassengerId`

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is all data in the column

ids =  T.loc[:,'PassengerId'].values

References
" The correct way to swap column values is by using row values: "

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer